# vSphere 6.5 API not returning performance data (C#)

Tags: c#, vmware, vsphere

I have code that works fine with the VMware vSphere 5, 5.5 and 6.0 API, that will return me performance stats with no problem. As soon as I point it at a vSphere 6.5 environment I get nothing returned by any object for any counter.

I have used powershell to query the 6.5 vCenter (not an appliance) and it returns data correctly so the vCenter server itself appears to be fine.

Are there any changes that I have missed for 6.5 which could stop me getting performance data from vCenter? It is hard for me to post code as it is entwined with some complex methods etc.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Please read [ask] and reduce your code to a [mcve]. You can't say "this code is not working" and then not show your code.

Comment: Here is a link to a code example.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12231713/ExampleCode.zip

This works against vSphere 5.5 and not against vSphere 6.5 (no data returned)

This code comes from the VMware Sample library!